# Populating a tabbed table

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, angular8, mongoose-schema

Okay, so I'm new to Angular, just under a week or so and I managed to get most of this app built thanks to dev docs.

I am trying to populate a tab table for job openings where clicking the title changes the description accordingly (such as here https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_tabulators_animate). I got the tabs to function just fine with static code, but now trying to pull from the mongodb, it only shows one of the entries in the "posts" collection, though the entire array of objects does come up in the console.

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

my home.component.html:

```
    <div class="content" *ngFor="let post of posts">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="col-md-12 open">
            <h3>Open Positions:</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="example-loading-shade" *ngIf="isLoadingResults">
        <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoadingResults"></mat-spinner>
      </div>
      <div class="row" [routerLink]="['/post']" >
        <div class="col-md-3" id="jobNames" data="this.posts">
          <div class="w3-bar w3-black">
            <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick='openLink(event, post._id)'>{{post.postTitle}}</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9" id="jobContainer">
          <div class="job w3-container w3-animate-opacity" id="post._id">
            <h3 class="jobSections">Date Posted: {{post.updated | date: 'dd MMM yyyy'}}</h3>
            <p [innerHTML]="post.postContent"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Post.js:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'), Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  category : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
  id: String,
  postTitle: String,
  postAuthor: String,
  postContent: String,
  postReference: String,
  created: { type: Date },
  updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from '../post/post';
import { PostService } from '../post.service';
import { HomeService } from '../home.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  post: Post = {
    category: '',
    id: '',
    postTitle: '',
    postAuthor: '',
    postContent: '',
    postReference: '',
    created: null,
    updated: null
  };
  posts: Post[] = [];
  isLoadingResults = true;

  constructor(private api: HomeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getPosts()
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.posts = res;
        console.log(this.posts);
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
      });
  }

}
```

jobs.js

```
function openLink(evt, animName) {
  var i, x, tablinks;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("job");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" w3-red", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(animName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " w3-red";
}
```

home.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Category } from './category/category';
import { Post } from './post/post';

const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/public/';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HomeService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCategories(): Observable<Category[]> {
    return this.http.get<Category[]>(apiUrl + 'category')
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => this.log('fetched Categories')),
        catchError(this.handleError('getCategories', []))
      );
  }

  getPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.http.get<Post[]>(apiUrl + 'post')
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => this.log('fetched Posts')),
        catchError(this.handleError('getPosts', []))
      );
  }

  getPostsByCategory(id: any): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.http.get<Post[]>(apiUrl + 'bycategory/' + id)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => this.log('fetched Posts')),
        catchError(this.handleError('getPosts', []))
      );
  }

  getPost(id: any): Observable<Post> {
    return this.http.get<Post>(apiUrl + 'post/' + id).pipe(
      tap(_ => console.log(`fetched post by id=${id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Post>(`getPost id=${id}`))
    );
  }

  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      console.error(error); // log to console instead
      this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

      return of(result as T);
    };
  }

  private log(message: string) {
    console.log(message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, and in case anyone else is looking for something similar

home.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from '../post/post';
import { PostService } from '../post.service';
import { HomeService } from '../home.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  post: Post = {
    category: '',
    id: '',
    postTitle: '',
    postAuthor: '',
    postContent: '',
    postReference: '',
    created: null,
    updated: null
  };
  posts: Post[] = [];
  isLoadingResults = true;
  selectedPost: Post = null;

  constructor(private api: HomeService) { }

  openLink(evt, animName) {
    var i, x, tablinks;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("job");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" w3-red", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(animName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " w3-red";
  }

  selectPost(post) {
    this.selectedPost = post;
    console.log(this.selectedPost);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getPosts()
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.posts = res;
        console.log(this.posts);
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
      }
    );
  }

}
```

home.component.html

```
<div class="col-md-12 open">
        <h3>Open Positions:</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="example-loading-shade" *ngIf="isLoadingResults">
        <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoadingResults"></mat-spinner>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2" id="jobNames">
          <div class="w3-bar w3-black">
            <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" *ngFor="let post of posts"
              (click)="selectPost(post)">{{post.postTitle}}</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10" id="jobContainer">
          <div class="job w3-container w3-animate-opacity" id="{{selectedPost.postTitle}}">
            <h3 class="jobSections">Date Posted: {{selectedPost.updated | date: 'dd MMM yyyy'}}</h3>
            <p innerHTML={{selectedPost.postContent}}></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how is designed your **HomeService** but...

I good solution is make in your Service a method getPosts with parameter like *section* o *tab name* and you can filter data with it

Then you can use it on HomeComponent easily

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.loadPosts('jobs'); // use first tab for default on load component
}

loadPosts(tabName) {
   this.api.getPosts(tanName)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.posts = res;
        console.log(this.posts);
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
      });
}
```

then you can use it on click

```
openLink(evt, animName) {
  /* your code */
  evt.currentTarget.className += " w3-red";
  let tabName = evt,currentTarget.innerText.trim() // trim(), maybe forget spaces  
  this.loadPosts(tabName);
}
```

if you have to do without parameter can be use pipeline filter or have a variable for all data and another for filtered data, then on click you change filtered data

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getPosts()
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.allPosts = res;      // <----- all post in a variable
        console.log(this.posts);
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
      });
}

openLink(evt, animName) {
  /* your code */
  evt.currentTarget.className += " w3-red";
  let tabName = evt,currentTarget.innerText.trim() // trim(), maybe forget spaces
  this.posts = this.allPosts.filter(post=> post.tabName == 'tabName');
}
```

## Edit

if you choose first option
best way is filter on server on receiving tabName parameter by api request
then the magic is made on server side

```
export class HomeService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { } 

  getPosts(tabName: string): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.http.get<Post[]>(apiUrl + 'post?tabName='+tabName)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => this.log('fetched Posts')),
        catchError(this.handleError('getPosts', []))
      );
  } 
}
```

Comment: Which file would I put this in? The home.service.ts? I added what I currently have above

Comment: HomeComponent, but you need implements code for HomeService and maybe on server too, this for first option

Comment: Sorry this isnt working either, now i'm not getting anything

Comment: I think it comes to the html, how do I write the ng-click so it reads the post._id?